# possible to nest method calls on to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
render :json => r.to_json(:methods => [:food_item => {:method => :price_value}])
```

but it's not working. Is something like this even possible?

thx

**edit 1**
no association

```
def food_item
  MenuItem.find(food_id)
end
```

Comment: Is `:food_item` an associated model?

Comment: it's a method that does a MenuItem.find(id) - has to be manually managed since there are two of them in this class

Comment: Check 4.1.2.2 Class name here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference

It sounds like you want an association like

    has_one :food_item, :class_name => "MenuItem"

Or belongs_to :food_item, :class_name => "MenuItem", :foreign_key => "food_id"

Comment: Pretty sure I can't do it because there are two of the same foreign models here. I managing it manually. thx

Comment: That's exactly what :class_name is for. You can have any number of "belongs_to :whatever_you_want_to_call_your_association" and ":class_name => MenuItem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is food_item an ActiveRecord association? If so, you could try

```
render :json => r.to_json(:include => { :food_item => { :only => :price_value } })
```

I'll refine my answer in response to "edit 1". First, remove your food_item method and add an actual association like this:

```
belongs_to :food_item, :class_name => "MenuItem", :foreign_key => "food_id"
```

and then do

```
render :json => r.to_json(:include => { :food_item => { :only => [:price_value] } })
```

Comment: the issue is that there are other elements like drink_item, dessert_item etc... which won't work in the structure described. I'm pretty sure it needs to be managed manually

Comment: Why won't they work? Why not just add `belongs_to :drink_item, :class_name => "MenuItem", :foreign_key => "drink_item"` and `belongs_to :dessert_item, :class_name => "MenuItem", :foreign_key => "dessert_id"` and so forth?

Comment: probably from having two separate but indentical relationships into the same model. Not exactly sure why (hence the original question). Wish I had a good answer for this - probably will just try to piece something together. I appreciate the help, I just don't think it can be done

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by "two separate but identical relationships into the same model". Can you clarify with specifics?

Comment: accepted the answer - this part of the app is pretty out-there. Most of it works great. Didn't get working though if someone stumbles across